# Get sum of unique customer ids each month, then group by month and age

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, format

From the below table I need to get the sum of unique customer coverage by month and age band:

| cust_id | cmpgn_mth | age_band | coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202309 | 18-34 | 1 |
| 1 | 202309 | 18-34 | 1 |
| 1 | 202308 | 18-34 | 1 |
| 2 | 202309 | 35-45 | 1 |
| 2 | 202308 | 35-45 | 0 |
| 2 | 202308 | 35-45 | 1 |
| 3 | 202309 | 18-34 | 1 |
| 3 | 202308 | 18-34 | 1 |
| 3 | 202308 | 18-34 | 1 |

This is the desired outcome. As you can see, even though customer '1' appears twice in the '202309' month, it should only be counted as a single coverage:

| cmpgn_mth | age_band | coverage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202309 | 18-34 | 2 |
| 202309 | 35-45 | 1 |
| 202308 | 18-34 | 2 |
| 202308 | 35-45 | 1 |

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried the below query without success, it gives me repeated rows as if it were still considering each cust_id per row.

`SELECT cmpgn_mth, age_band, SUM(cross_sell) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AS coverage FROM mytable GROUP BY cmpgn_mth, age_band, cross_sell, cust_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select cmpgn_mth, age_band, 
  count(distinct if(coverage = 1, cust_id, null)) as coverage
from your_table
group by cmpgn_mth, age_band
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]